# Majento Retrive all orders without filter in Asp.Net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the following API https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi for my asp.net webform project.

With the guidelines everything is working fine with filters.

```
 var filter = new Magento.RestApi.Models.Filter();
 filter.FilterExpressions.Add(new FilterExpression("name", ExpressionOperator.like, "L%"));
 filter.PageSize = 100;
 filter.Page = 0;
 var response = await client.GetProducts(filter);
 var sCode = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetOrders(filter ));
 MagentoApiResponse<IList<Magento.RestApi.Models.Order>> product = sCode.Result;
```

Is there any way where I can rertive all orders at once without filter?

If I remove the filter parameter, receiving the error given below.

```
var sCode = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetOrders());
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an issue with just not adding the `FilterExpression`?

Comment: Hi @user7217806 I have edited my question, have attached screenshot. The above NuGet makes filters as compulsion

Comment: I did not mean not passing the `filter` variable to `GetOrders`, just to remove the second line (`filter.FilterExpressions.Add...`).